# jquery - serializeArray() error

Tags: jquery, serializearray

im trying to pass an array as a string

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var args = {};
$('.radio').click(function(){
    var ob = $(this).siblings('select');
    $('#uploader-wrapper').html(pre_load());
    $('.radio').siblings('select').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    ob.removeAttr('disabled');
    args[ob.attr('name')] = $(':selected', ob).text();
    loader( args.serializeArray() );
})
$('select[name=foo]').change(function(){
    var ob = $(this);
    $('#uploader-wrapper').html(pre_load());
    args[ob.attr('name')] = $(':selected', ob).text();
    loader( args.serializeArray() );
});
});
```

but i get an error

`args.serializeArray is not a function`

can anyone see what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`serializeArray`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) is only available on jQuery objects. Since `args` is a vanilla object, use [`$.param`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/):

```
loader($.param(args));
```

Comment: Useful for me as well! +

Answer (score 2):

`args` is a normal javascript object, not a JQuery object.

From [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/),

> This method can act on a jQuery object
>   that has selected individual form
>   elements, such as `<input>`, `<textarea>`,
>   and `<select>`.